# Generic <T extends A> class uses A static field instead of T's one

Tags: java, class, inheritance

Here's my situation

```
public abstract class Actions {

    public static Actions STAND;
    public static Actions ATTACK;
    public static Actions COLONIZE;
    public static Actions DEFEND;
    public static Actions TURN_CW;
    public static Actions TURN_CCW;
    public static Actions DIE;

    public abstract long[] getFramesDurations();
    public abstract int[] getBaseTiles();
}

public class SimpleActions extends Actions{

    public static Actions STAND = new SimpleActions( new long[]{120,120,120,120,120,120,120}, new int[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6});
    public static Actions ATTACK = new SimpleActions( new long[]{120,120,120,120,120,120,120,120,120}, new int[]{7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15});
    public static Actions COLONIZE = new SimpleActions( new long[]{120,120,120,120,120,120,120}, new int[]{7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15});
    public static Actions DEFEND = new SimpleActions(new long[]{1}, new int[]{1});
    public static Actions TURN_CW = new SimpleActions( new long[]{1}, new int[]{1});
    public static Actions TURN_CCW = new SimpleActions( new long[]{1}, new int[]{1});
    public static Actions DIE = new SimpleActions( new long[]{1}, new int[]{1});

    private final long[] mActionFramesDurations;
    private final int[] mActionBaseTiles;

    SimpleActions(long[] pActionFramesDurations, int[] pActionBaseTiles) {
        mActionFramesDurations = pActionFramesDurations;
        mActionBaseTiles = pActionBaseTiles;
    }

    public long[] getFramesDurations()
    {
        return mActionFramesDurations;
    }

    public int[] getBaseTiles()
    {
        return mActionBaseTiles;
    }
}

public abstract class A<T extends Actions> {
    A() {
        doSomething(T.STAND);
    }

    protected void doSomething(Actions action) { use action somewhere}
}

public class B extends A<SimpleActions> {
    B() {
        super();
    }
}
```

I always get nullPointerException when the constructor of A calls doSomething because action is null..

Since B extends A i was expecting it to use SimpleActions.STAND, and not Actions.STAND.

What am i doing wrong? How should i do this?

Comment: You're calling `super()` from class `B` - at the superclass level, all the compiler knows is that `T` extends `Actions`, not `SimpleActions`. Have you considered using an `Enum` for your actions, or is there a need to "override" them? If there is, Java doesn't do static inheritance like you might expect from Smalltalk; as your code is, the static declarations in your `Actions` class are sort of pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java Language Specification [writes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.4):

> The members of a type variable X with bound T & I1 ... In are the members of the intersection type (§4.9) T & I1 ... In appearing at the point where the type variable is declared.

That's why the expression `T.STAND` refers to `Actions.STAND`, not `SimpleActions.STAND`.

`Actions.STAND` and `SimpleActions.STAND` are different fields (unlike non-static methods, fields can not be overriden.)

That already highlights one way to delegate to the subclass: Define an accessor method (a getter) that subclass must override:

```
abstract class Actions {
    abstract Actions stand();
}

class SimpleActions extends Actions {
    private static final Actions STAND = ...;

    @Override Actions stand() { return STAND;}
}
```

and invoke

```
t.stand();
```

where t is an instance of T provided to `A` upon construction. Or perhaps move this method into a different type (`MotionRegistry`?) and provide an instance of that upon construction of `A`.

That said, your design appears pretty complicated, I can't shake the feeling that your code could be simplified (do you need the distinction between Actions and SimpleActions if both describe the same actions?)

Comment: Thanks! Do it works even if i make the methods static?
Yes, i do, since i have many different classes that extends A, and each class has his own actions, that logically are always the same, but graphically are different.

Comment: @Makers_F: No, it won't work with static methods. The point of static methods is to tie the method to a specific class implementation. This approach takes advantage of polymorphism, which only works with non-static methods.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior at first i thought generics would have helped me, but the more i use them the more i find them weak.. Btw thanks for the tip! Back to writing a lot of boring code for a thing that seams so easy..

Comment: Using public static non-final variables here is a real mistake because they can be reassigned.  Referencing them from a generic type is confusing. This is a bad design in several ways. Generics would likely work very well for you if you used them correctly.

Comment: @Makers_F: While generics are weaker in Java than they are in, say, C#, that has nothing to do with this particular problem. As you spend more time doing software development, you will hopefully come to understand why allingeek's comment is correct. You need the right tool for the right job, and static fields are simply the wrong approach to solving this particular problem in the first place.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior yes, i now changed it to a singleton(so i can access it wherever i need without bringing always in my classes a field for this) that implements an interface like meriton said. It's probably true that i don't understand java's generics, but i hope too that experience will teach me! Thanks for you effort!

Answer (score 3):

The type parameters to a generic are not known at run time.  In other words, at run time, there's no difference between an `A<Actions>` and an `A<SimpleActions>`.  The jvm therefore can't tell that you want `SimpleActions.STAND`, rather than `Actions.STAND`.  If you need the type parameters to be known at run time, you'll need to carry them around in a separate variable.

Read up on "run time type erasure" if this isn't clear.

**Edited following your comment -** 
If you're only doing this logic in the constructor, you could make the constructor look like

```
A( Class<? extends Action> actionType ){
    if( SimpleActions.class.isAssignableFrom( actionType )){
        doSomething( SimpleActions.STAND );
    }
    else{
        doSomething( Actions.STAND );
    }
}
```

If you need the same logic outside of the constructor, then make a member variable of type `Class<? extends Action>` inside `A` to store the `actionType`.

Comment: yeah, i read about it. But how can i carry it in a separate variable?
Can you show me some (pseudo) code?

Comment: This seams a lot of work, in addition i'll use many king of Actions implementations, so it will turn out as a wall of if else